# c# soap and logmein

Tags: c#, web-services, csv, soap

As logmeinrescue doesn't support batch users creation using a simple csv upload or similar and instead offers the ability to create user accounts using http post and get or by using soap I thought I would look into this.

Unfortunately following the code example in this [link](https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/RescueAPI/API/API_Rescue_createUsers.html) I have been unable to work out how to utilize the SOAP aspect of the code as I have never had previous experience using it.

So far I have written a fairly basic program that reads in the csv with all the user account data needed for creation and would loop through and assign the values needed.

If anyone could assist it would be greatly appreciated, I have tried to look up some documentation in regards to c# and soap but I was unable to find something that really helped me with configuring for logmein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c# example at the bottom of documentation you link to looks helpful but flawed. `APISoapClient` does not have a `CookieContainer` property so I would try it without the line of code that tries to set it. Later in the code there is a call to `sAPI.createUsers` but the example has not defined `sAPI`, I think they meant to re-use `proxy`.

To get started the easy way, right-click your project References and select Add Service Reference. Enter their endpoint and click GO:
https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/api/API.asmx

If you change the namespace from Service1 to match the example (APIServiceReference) your code will look like the example. From then on you can perform API operations basically just like you were dealing with classes, the SOAP mess is abstracted away for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! a couple of things oddly the line
`requestAuthCodeRet authCodeRet = proxy.requestAuthCode(out sAuthCode, sEmail, sPwd);`
VS is suggesting to remove the out from sAuthCode and use out sPwd not sure why it would make that suggestion.

I'm also unsure as to why createUsers in `CREATEUSERSINFO ret = createUsers(new[] { userData }, sAuthCode);` is being flagged, everything else appears to be working but I wont know until I can run the code.

Comment: I think you will need to experiment, maybe even contact their support. Clearly their documentation is sloppy. I've never used their API, I just based my advice on consuming services in general.